# Prevent blank page on bad file download

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, asp.net-web-api

In our Angular JS application, I am downloading a file by simply calling `window.location`.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" ng-repeat="file in files">
        <div class="well well-sm truncate">
            <a href="" title="Download {{file.FileName}}" ng-click="download(file)" ><b>{{file.FileName}}</b></a><br />
            <small>{{(file.FileSize/1024)|number:2}} KB</small><br />
            <i class="fa fa-trash CP text-danger pull-right" ng-show="mUser.Role>=20" title="Delete file" ng-click="deletefiles(file.AttID)"></i>
            <small>Uploaded by <a href="user/{{file.AddedBy}}">{{file.AddedByName}}</a> on {{file.Created|date:'dd MMM yyyy'}}</small>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular method:

```
$scope.download = function (ff) {
  if (confirm('Download this file?')) window.location = "api/files/download?token=" + $rootScope.token + "&IDKey=" + ff.IDKey;
}
```

Web API Controller Method:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage download(string Token, string IDKey)
{
    HttpResponseMessage lResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    // Validate request
    Result lRes = UserClass.GetUserByToken(Token);
    if (!lRes.IsSuccess)
    {
        lResponse.Content = new StringContent("User Token is invalid");
        lResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
        return lResponse;
    }

    // Get File object
    AttClass lAtt = AttClass.GetFile(IDKey);
    if (!lAtt.IsOk)
    {
        lResponse.Content = new StringContent("Attachment ID Key is invalid");
        lResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        return lResponse;
    }

    // Return file
    lResponse.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(lAtt.GetFullPath(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
    lResponse.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = lAtt.FileName };
    lResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    return lResponse;
}
```

The file download works very well when `Token` and `IDKey` is valid. However, in other cases, the user is shown a blank page with a simple error message. Can I prevent this and just display an alert on the original page with the reason why the download failed?

PS: I do **not** want to use the HTML5 SaveAs functionality or filesaver.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

1- Did you try downloading file using iframe instead of the using
   window.location

```
document.getElementById("myiframe").src="api/files/download?token=" + $rootScope.token + "&IDKey=" + ff.IDKey;
```

and the check the iframe body

```
document.getElementById('myiframe').contentDocument.body.innerHTML
```

**Re EDIT**

```
document.getElementById("myiframe").src="your url";
document.getElementById("myiframe").addEventListener("load",
function(){ 
console.log(this.contentDocument.contentType);
if(!(document.getElementById("myiframe").contentDocument.contentType=="application/octet-stream")) 
alert("Downlaod Failed");
else 
alert("Thank you for downloading");
});
```

Comment: How would I notify the user when the download didn't work? The response from the server might take a while.

Comment: document.getElementById("myiframe").src="your url";



document.getElementById("myiframe").addEventListener("load",

function(){ 

console.log(this.contentDocument.contentType);

if(!(document.getElementById("myiframe").contentDocument.contentType=="application/octet-stream")) 

alert("Downlaod Failed");
else 
alert("Thank you for downloading");
});

Comment: Worked beautifully! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its very dificult to handle server response when you are using `window.location`.
You can use ajax call in angularJs to download or you can check your response too.

`$http({
            url: 'server/url',
            method: "POST",
            responseType: 'arraybuffer'
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {`
            `//check your response here`

```
        //smaple code for excel download
        var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"});
        var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var anchor = angular.element('<a/>');
        anchor.attr({
            href: objectUrl,
            target: '_blank',
            download: fileName + '_' + new Date().getTime() + '.xlsx'
        })[0].click();
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

    });
```

`

Comment: Thanks. But this is exactly what I want to avoid - it looks more like a hack than a robust solution. Until HTML5 SaveAs functionality is implemented well in all browsers, I'd try to avoid this.